# ForEach On Error GoTo Resume Next not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/err-object.html). I've created a button with the following click handler:

```
Private Sub SqrtButton_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each cell In rng
        On Error GoTo InvalidValue:
        cell.Value = Sqr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    Exit Sub

InvalidValue:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " at cell " & cell.Address
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

According to the tutorial, the program should display two error messages for cells B4 and B5 and replace values in the remaining cells. But, when I run the code, only the first cell value is replaced (B2) and no error messages are displayed.

The example is available to [download](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/excel-files/err-object.xls) and it doesn't work either.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with this code. Maybe you didn't select the whole range before clicking on the button?

Comment: The code is fine, but it expects you to select the range before clicking the button.

Comment: Are you selecting all the relevant cells and not just the first one (B2)

Comment: I did select the range. I also tried replacing `Selection` with `Range("B2:B6")` with the same result.

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you break on the `For` loop (F9) and then step through (F8) line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range is based off of the selection (highlighted cells), select all 5 cells  (B2:B6) and then click the button. The code seemed to work fine for me when I did this.

Be kind and leave feedback! :)

Comment: And this is why you don't write VBA code against `Selection` =)

Comment: I did select the range. I also tried replacing `Selection` with `Range("B2:B6")` with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but it really bothers me that the `On Error GoTo` syntax could be considered good practice.  Always avoid that if you can.  Here is the same code, but rewritten to avoid the On Error GoTo statement:

```
Private Sub SqrtButton_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Value >= 0 Then
            cell.Value = Sqr(cell.Value)
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Value [" & cell.Value & "] at cell " & cell.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```